# media querie não funciona

Tags: css, html5

olá, estou tentando fazer com que o background de uma section fique com uma cor no mobile e com uma imagem no desktop mas não funciona. Vou mandar o código e o print de como fica.

Aparentemente parece estar certo, mas não funciona de jeito nenhum. Poderiam me ajudar?

[image: mobile]

[image: desktop]

```css
@media (min-width: 1001px) {
#slice-mobile {

    background-image: url(assets/img/backgrounds/notebook2.jpg);
    background-position: bottom;
    background-position-y: 12%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    #slice-mobile { 

    background-color: #009976 !important 

    }
}
```

```html
<section class="slice slice-xl slice1 slicexl1" id="slice-mobile" >
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row row-grid align-items-center">

                <div class="col-lg-6 agenda1">
                        <div class="pt-lg-lg pb-lg-sm text-center text-lg-left">
                            <h2 class="h2 text-white mb-2"><span style="border-bottom: 3px solid #5E00DE;">Agenda</span> médica completa</h2>
                            <p class="lead text-white lh-180">Utilize o Módulo de Agenda para fazer uma gestão completa de todos os seus agendamentos, incluindo atendimentos de ambulatório como consultas e retornos, ou mesmo procedimentos ou atendimentos específicos.</p>
                            <!-- <div class="countdown h2 text-white" data-countdown-date="12/01/2018" data-countdown-label="hide"></div> -->

                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li style="color: #fff;" class="py-2"><i class="fas fa-check" style="color: #5E00DE;"></i> Visualização da agenda por dia, semana ou mês.
                        </li>
                        <li style="color: #fff;" class="py-2"><i class="fas fa-check" style="color: #5E00DE;"></i> Agendamento por profissional, procedimento e local.
                        </li>
                        <li style="color: #fff;" class="py-2"><i class="fas fa-check" style="color: #5E00DE;"></i> Confirmação de consultas e retornos e alertas de compromissos.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                            <a href="https://localhost/landing_agenda/contato.php" id="iconeView2" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-translate--hover mt-4"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-right arrow"></i> Fale com nossos consultores</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: O que não funciona a imagem??

Comment: Se eu colocar a imagem como padrão, a cor não aparecer no mobile (continua aparecendo a imagem). E se eu colocar cor como padrão, a imagem não aparece...

Comment: Bom, pelo meno aí no seu código não vai funcionar mesmo. Os breakpoints estão apontando para as mesmas medidas. Concorda comigo se tiver uma largura mínima de 1000px e uma largura maxima  de 1000px da na mesma???

Comment: então como teria que ser feito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue um modelo que fiz com base no seu código.

Repare que o Bootstrap 4 é *mobile first* então ele usa `min-width`, o que quer dizer que só quando a tela tive no mínimo 1001px de largura ele vai colocar a imagem no background. Se a tela for menor que 1001px ele vai usar a cor do BG.

Veja o exemplo. ***Execute tb em "Página toda"*** para ver que quando em larguras maiores que 1001px a imagem aparece no BG.

```css
#slice-mobile { 
    background-color: #009976;
}

@media (min-width: 1001px) {
    #slice-mobile {
        background-image: url(https://placecage.com/100/100);
        background-position: bottom;
        background-position-y: 12%;
    }
}
```

```html
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <section class="slice slice-xl slice1 slicexl1" id="slice-mobile" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-grid align-items-center">

            <div class="col-lg-6 agenda1">
                    <div class="pt-lg-lg pb-lg-sm text-center text-lg-left">
                        <h2 class="h2 text-white mb-2"><span style="border-bottom: 3px solid #5E00DE;">Agenda</span> médica completa</h2>
                        <p class="lead text-white lh-180">Utilize o Módulo de Agenda para fazer uma gestão completa de todos os seus agendamentos, incluindo atendimentos de ambulatório como consultas e retornos, ou mesmo procedimentos ou atendimentos específicos.</p>
                        <!-- <div class="countdown h2 text-white" data-countdown-date="12/01/2018" data-countdown-label="hide"></div> -->

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li style="color: #fff;" class="py-2"><i class="fas fa-check" style="color: #5E00DE;"></i> Visualização da agenda por dia, semana ou mês.
                    </li>
                    <li style="color: #fff;" class="py-2"><i class="fas fa-check" style="color: #5E00DE;"></i> Agendamento por profissional, procedimento e local.
                    </li>
                    <li style="color: #fff;" class="py-2"><i class="fas fa-check" style="color: #5E00DE;"></i> Confirmação de consultas e retornos e alertas de compromissos.
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

                        <a href="https://localhost/landing_agenda/contato.php" id="iconeView2" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-translate--hover mt-4"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-right arrow"></i> Fale com nossos consultores</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: no seu exemplo funciona sim, quando eu replico no meu não funciona. mesmo importando os links que você colocou

Comment: @Anne nesse caso sugiro que vc coloque o seu CSS inteiro na sua pergunta. Edite a pergunta e coloque tudo que vc tem de CSS, pois foi algo que vc fez lá que está interferindo nesse comportamento.

Comment: não cabe o CSS todo :( eu acho que o problema eh na imagem. Quando coloquei a mesma imagem que vc funcionou, aí quando coloco a minha não funciona :(

Comment: @Anne tente colocar essa propriedade junto com o CSS da imagem `background-size: cover` veja se vai aparecer a sua imagem. Se ela não aparecer pode ser pq o caminho da imagem no diretório está errado, ou a imagem é um .PNG por exemplo e vc está chamando um .JPG

Answer (score 1):

Tente colocar assim:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1001px) {
#slice-mobile {

    background-image: url(assets/img/backgrounds/notebook2.jpg);
    background-position: bottom;
    background-position-y: 12%;
    }
}
```

Comment: assim também não vai :(

Answer (score 1):

Para deixar com uma cor no mobile, não precisa declarar um `max-width`. Deixe por assim dizer como padrão com uma cor. Daí quando ele for de 1001 ou maior, vai trocar pela imagem.

Faltou algo importante. Não pode ter `!important`.

```
#slice-mobile { 
   background-color: #009976; 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1001px) {
   #slice-mobile {
       background-image: url(assets/img/backgrounds/notebook2.jpg);
       background-position: bottom;
       background-position-y: 12%;
       background-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

Comment: não muda, tentei assim também e não vai :( já não sei o que fazer mais

Comment: quando eu tiro o importante fica tudo branco. não aparece nem cor nem imagem

Comment: Você consegue colocar no CodePen para vermos?

Comment: eu já resolvi @Diego Souza, obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Olá, segue um codepen https://codepen.io/michaelsampietro/pen/eLdaYr

Como você mencionou que já tentou alterar para isso: `@media screen and (min-width: 1001px)`, verifique se a seguinte tag está definida no `head` do seu html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Caso queira ler mais sobre, segue um link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: já está sim, não funciona

Comment: exemplo com cor funciona, mas preciso de um exemplo com background-image

Comment: Tente colocar background-image: none; antes da linha que chama a cor verde de fundo.

Comment: não funciona mesmo assim :(

Comment: @Anne é só colocar o background atrelhado novamente a propriedade se é isso que você precisa. Por exemplo background: #000 url(assets/img/backgrounds/notebook1.jpg); E dentro do media query background: #FFF url(assets/img/backgrounds/notebook2.jpg);